# Oops, that dumb coworker didn't tell me the password

Tags: story

Today, after moving to the new office, you realize that the previous occupant didn't leave the password. Oops...

But he did leave a note. What is the password?

> atchiinson, ttopeka, and santa fe
>
> ssouthern paciific
>
> union pacific
>
> penn centtral
>
> denver and rio grande
>
> new york central
>
> hharvard conneecticut
>
> ---
>
> Accordinc to many teachess, Wikisedia is nol a goid sourke, beceuse it san be emited ey anybody. I agree.
>
> Spallilg leally reclly realay peally sounts!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To start,

We can highlight the spelling errors in the note:
atchi**i**nson, **t**topeka, and santa fe
**s**southern paci**i**fic
union pacific
penn cent**t**ral
denver and rio grande
new york central
**h**harvard conne**e**cticut
Accordin**c** to many teache**s**s, Wiki**s**edia is no**l** a go**i**d sour**k**e, bec**e**use it **s**an be e**m**ited **e**y anybody. I agree.
Sp**a**lli**l**g **l**eally re**c**lly real**a**y **p**eally **s**ounts!

Isolating these, we get

> i-t-s-i-t-h-e-c-s-s-l-i-k-e-s-m-e-a-l-l-c-a-p-s

so the password is probably

> ITHECSSLIKESME (its - I the css likes me all caps)

Comment: In the first word you marked for a spelling error, I don't believe that the "n" is an error. This would correct a slight error in your answer as well.

Comment: +1; just fix the error, and then you're done!

Comment: @TzuLi just fixed it!

Comment: pa-ping! Accepted!